# C++11 POD structure initializing error

Tags: c++, c++11, initialization, initializer-list

I have confusing situation with simple code:

```
struct Item {
    size_t span{};
};

int main() {
    Item item{1}; // error is here
    return 0;
}
```

While compiling this I have following error:

```
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:8:13: error: no matching function for call to ‘Item::Item(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)’
     Item i{1};
             ^
test.cpp:8:13: note: candidates are:
test.cpp:3:8: note: constexpr Item::Item()
 struct Item {
        ^
test.cpp:3:8: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided
test.cpp:3:8: note: constexpr Item::Item(const Item&)
test.cpp:3:8: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘int’ to ‘const Item&’
test.cpp:3:8: note: constexpr Item::Item(Item&&)
test.cpp:3:8: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘int’ to ‘Item&&’
```

Why `g++` tries to find a `ctor` for `initializer list` in this case instead of simple C-style structure object creating?

If I remove `{}` from `size_t span{}` it compiles successfully.

It also happens if I change the line to `size_t span = 0` so it seems to be some initialization in declaration issue which exists since c++11.

Comment: `Item` is not an aggregate type in C++11 (it is an aggregate in C++14)

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki thanks, just found out why I did think it will be okay - read a book about c++14, that's why I thought it is legal for c++11 too.

Comment: C++ has not had structures since 1985. The keyword `struct` declares a _class_.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usign `Item item{1};` means you're doing *list-initialisation* (of `item`). List initialisation is defined as follows:

- if the type is an aggregate, aggregate initialisation (what you refer to as "C-style struct object creating") happens
- ...
- if the type is a class, constructors are considered

Your class has no constructors. It is also not a (C++11) aggregate, because it contains an initialiser for a non-static data member.

Note that this restriction (member initialisers) was lifted in C++14, so `Item` *is* a C++14 aggregate and your code, while not valid C++11, is valid C++14.